# How to read data from one xls file and write it into another xls file

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have dev.xls file with sheet name as "Electricity". In my vb.net winform application, I want to read all this data and write it into another xls file (Test.xls) with sheet name as "Electricity_Processed".

Looking for a way to do this without using other dll's or Interop

Any suggestions please?

Comment: isn't this your 3rd or 4th time asking roughly the same question? didn't this answer to your earlier question get you going? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308205/how-to-convert-csv-file-to-xls-file-in-vb-net/6308645#6308645

Comment: Is there anyway I can solve this without using other dll's or Interop

Comment: I mean just reading cell by cell and write it in corresponding cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more serious answer is to use late binding. Late binding however requires that MS Excel is installed on the system running the program.:

```
Option Strict Off

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim xl As Object = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    xl.visible = True
    xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\junk\junk.xls")
    Dim sht1 As Object = xl.Sheets(1) '1-based
    Dim rng As Object = sht1.Range("A2", "A2") 'get the cell
    MsgBox(rng.Value) 'show the value
    Dim rng2 As Object = sht1.Range("B3", "B3") 'get the cell
    rng2.Value = "Hello" 'set the value
  End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OleDb`, which supports reading and writing of Excel files. [Google with the keywords `OleDb` and `Excel` has tons of results](http://www.google.com/search?q=oledb%20excel), and there's also a Microsoft KB article on exactly this subject:

- [How To Use ADO.NET to Retrieve and Modify Records in an Excel Workbook With Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316934/en-us)

Basically, you can use simple `SELECT` statements to read data, and `INSERT` statements to write data. Excel sheets are represented as tables, so you can use `CREATE TABLE` to create your `Electricity_Processed` sheet.

Answer (score 0):

No DLLs or Interop? You can write your own XLS parser, I suppose :-) The XLS format is described here: http://www.wotsit.org/list.asp?fc=6